# How to see GHResponse on map by using GraphHopperWeb

Tags: java, graphhopper

I am trying to use GraphHopperWeb in order to see route response on the web. 
I am probably does not know how to use it, but i don't get what is wrong.
I am using the following code (in java) in order to find some path from one point to other point as the following:

```
    GHRequest req = new GHRequest(32.070113, 34.790266, 32.067103, 34.777861).
            setWeighting("fastest")
            .setVehicle("car");

    GraphHopperWeb gh = new GraphHopperWeb();
    gh.load("http://localhost:8989/route");


    gh.setInstructions(true);
    GHResponse response = gh.route(req);

    System.out.println(response);
```

I get the following print screen:

nodes:24: (32.07012,34.79021), (32.07011,34.7902), (32.07006,34.79019), (32.07028,34.78867), (32.07029,34.78852), (32.07029,34.78847), (32.06994,34.78814), (32.06942,34.78761), (32.06931,34.7875), (32.06912,34.78731), (32.06862,34.78667), (32.06756,34.78546), (32.06627,34.78391), (32.06617,34.78375), (32.06604,34.7836), (32.06622,34.78317), (32.06768,34.78009), (32.06769,34.77998), (32.06767,34.77992), (32.06654,34.77915), (32.06624,34.77894), (32.0666,34.77764), (32.06709,34.7778), (32.06708,34.77785), [(0,Continue onto הנציב,6.186,742), (2,Turn right onto שדרות יהודית,164.23,19706), (-2,Turn left onto מנחם בגין, 2,142.253,9310), (0,Continue onto מנחם בגין,517.411,31039), (2,Turn right onto לינקולן,394.313,28388), (-1,Turn slight left onto יהודה הלוי,183.917,13240), (2,Turn right onto בלפור,128.87,9278), (2,Turn right onto שדרות רוטשילד,56.539,4070), (2,Turn right onto המגיד,4.589,550), (4,Finish!,0.0,0)]

but when i open explorer with the address "http://localhost:8989/route" i am getting the following error:

{"info":{"copyrights":["GraphHopper","OpenStreetMap contributors"],"errors":[{"details":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","message":"At least 2 points has to be specified, but was:0"}]}}

I don't get how can i see GHResponse (the routing path i have found) on the map thru explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the external [GraphHopperWeb client](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-java-client#usage) is similar to the usage of the embedded routing [described here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/routing.md) and the points for visualization can be fetched via getPoints or the turn instructions via getInstructions:

```
GHRequest req = new GHRequest(32.070113, 34.790266, 32.067103, 34.777861)
   .setWeighting("fastest")
   .setVehicle("car");

GHResponse res = gh.route(req);

if(res.hasErrors()) {
   // handle or throw exceptions res.getErrors()
   return;
}

// get path geometry information (latitude, longitude and optionally elevation)
PointList pl = res.getPoints();
// distance of the full path, in meter
double distance = res.getDistance();
// time of the full path, in milliseconds
long millis = res.getTime();
// get information per turn instruction
InstructionList il = res.getInstructions();
```

Comment: yes, I am familiar with that but how can i see the PointList marked on map thru explorer?